# Fluent validation for bool values is not returning custom error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on fluent validations, so I have a simple class as:

**Entity**

```
 public class Visit 
    {
       public bool BillableVisit { get; set; }
    }
```

**Validator**

```
 public class VisitValidator : AbstractValidator<Visit>, ITransientDependency
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.BillableVisit).NotNull().WithMessage("The BillableVisit is required");
    }
```

**Request**:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task InsertAsync(VisitDto visitDto)
{
    var visit = ObjectMapper.Map<VisitDto, Visit>(visitDto);
    var validationResults = await _visitValidator.ValidateAsync(visit);

    if (!validationResults.IsValid)
    {
        var validationErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults.Errors)
        {
            if (validationResult is null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            validationErrors.Add(new ValidationResult(validationResult.ErrorMessage, new[] { validationResult.PropertyName }));
        }
        throw new AbpValidationException("Validation failed", validationErrors);
    }
}
```

**Request Json**

```
{
...,
"billableVisit": null
}
```

So, when I request it, instead return the custom message it is returning as:

> "error": {
> "code": null,
> "message": "Your request is not valid!",
> "details": "The following errors were detected during validation.\r\n - The JSON value could not be converted to
> System.Boolean. Path: $.billableVisit | LineNumber: 55 |
> BytePositionInLine: 23.\r\n",
> "data": {},
> "validationErrors": [
> {
> "message": "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.billableVisit | LineNumber: 55 |
> BytePositionInLine: 23.",
> "members": [
> "$.billableVisit"
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

I also tried to change the validator to  `.Must(x => x == false || x == true)` but still the same issue; how can I return the custom message correctly?

Comment: The property cannot be `null` ever. `bool` is a value type. So if you try to deserialize `null` to a `bool` property it will throw (except you configured your serializer to use default values instead in that case). Try making the property a `bool?`. Then things should look differently. BTW what I said is what this message is trying to tell you _"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean"_.

Comment: I changed the property to `public bool? BillableVisit { get; set; }`, but still getting the same issue @Fildor

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mZxkjd <- Cannot reproduce. What are your Json Serialization settings?

Comment: Ohh I was understanding your answer, I changed the nulleable value on the receiving DTO object instead the entity itself, it is working now! thanks @Fildor